# How to hide my file name (checker.php) from my server URL

Tags: php, url, hide

this is my first checking project and now its going on finish and please help me to hide checker.php (my file name) from my server  URL
[How to hide (.php) from my server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmcMP.png)

[image]

Comment: what do you want the url to be?

Comment: JUST I WANNA PUT ANY example.com

Comment: then you dont need the category id?

Comment: that's no problem sir but no one can't get i am coding by php language

Comment: `/todo/3` `/todo/?categpry_id=3` ... cant answer if i dont know what you actually want

Answer (score 0):

You could use a .htdocs file. https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

You can't easy do this via PHP because the browser makes the request to the specific url.